# What is the proper way to use raw sql in Django with params?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-3.0

Consider that I have a *"working"* PostgreSQL query -

```
SELECT sum((cart->> 'total_price')::int) as total_price FROM core_foo;
```

I want to use the raw query within Django, and I used the below code to get the result-

```py
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    query = """SELECT sum((cart->> 'total_price')::int) as total_price FROM core_foo;"""
    cursor.execute(query, [])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row)
```

But, I need to make this hard-coded query into a dynamic one with `params`( maybe, to prevent SQL injections). So, I converted the Django query into -

```py
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    query = 'SELECT sum((%(field)s->> %(key)s::int)) as foo FROM core_foo;'
    kwargs = {
        'field': 'cart',
        'key': 'total_price',
    }
    cursor.execute(query, kwargs)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error -

```
DataError: invalid input syntax for type integer: "total_price"
LINE 1: SELECT sum(('cart'->> 'total_price'::int)) as foo FROM core_...
```

Note that; the ***`field`*** ( here the value is `cart`) input gets an additional quote symbol during the execution, which doesn't match the syntax.

---

#### Question

What is the proper way to pass *`kwargs`* to the `cursor.execute(...)`

1. with single/double quotes?
2. without single/double quotes?

Comment: you can only replace parameters with that construct never column names table names or json fields, for that you must use the string concatenation or replacing functionality

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* pass field names through the parameters. The parameters only escape values.

You thus work with:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    field = 'cart'
    query = f'SELECT sum(({field}->> %(key)s::int)) as foo FROM core_foo;'
    kwargs = {
        'key': 'total_price',
    }
    cursor.execute(query, kwargs)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row)
```

This will of course *not* escape the field so if the `field` contains raw SQL, it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

This is one of the very many reasons *not* to use raw SQL queries.

If `cart` is a [**`JSONField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField), you can [*query the `JSONField`* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield):

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

field = 'cart'
key = 'total_price'
Foo.objects.aggregate(
    total=Sum(Cast(f'{field}__{key}', output_field=models.IntegerField()))
)['total']
```

Comment: The explanation makes sense! But, the Django ORM query doesn't seem to be working (FYI: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76160437/8283848))

Comment: @JPG: what type of field is `cart` in the `Foo` model?

Comment: It is `JSONField` (postgres DB backend with Django 3.1.x)

Comment: @JPG: and what i the problem? What error do you get?

Comment: I created a separate SO post for that since I felt the issue supposed to be added in a better way - feel free to check https://stackoverflow.com/q/76160437/8283848

Comment: @JPG: are you sure all the `total_price` data are integers? Not a `null`, JSON object, something else?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that all the `total_price` are integers without any `null` value