# Aggregate sum of values from Django JSONField

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-jsonfield, jsonfield

Consider I have a simple model setup with **`JSONField`**

```py
from django.db import models

import random


def simple_json_callable():
    return {"amount": random.randint(1, 100)}


def nested_json_callable():
    data = {
        "l1": {
            "l2": {
                "l3": {
                    "amount": random.randint(1, 100)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return data


class Foo(models.Model):
    simple_json = models.JSONField(default=simple_json_callable)
    nested_json = models.JSONField(default=nested_json_callable)
```

I want to get the sum of ***`amount`*** key from both `simple_json` and `nested_json` fields.

I tried the following queries

#### Case 1: Annotate and then aggregate

```py
result = Foo.objects.annotate(
    simple_json_amount=Cast('simple_json__amount', output_field=models.IntegerField()),
    nested_json_amount=Cast('nested_json__l1__l2__l3__amount', output_field=models.IntegerField()),
).aggregate(
    simple_json_total=models.Sum('simple_json_amount'),
    nested_json_total=models.Sum('nested_json_amount'),
)
```

#### Case 2: Aggregate

```py
result = Foo.objects.aggregate(
    simple_json_total=models.Sum(Cast('simple_json__amount', output_field=models.IntegerField())),
    nested_json_total=models.Sum(Cast('nested_json__l1__l2__l3__amount', output_field=models.IntegerField())),

)
```

In both cases, I got the error

```
django.db.utils.DataError: cannot cast jsonb object to type integer
```

#### Question

What is the proper way to aggregate sum of values from a `JSONField` in Django?

---

#### Version

- Django 3.1.X
- Python 3.9.X

Answer (score 2):

### For `Django==3.2.X` and newer versions

You can use the *"double-underscore"* to span the relationship and can get the aggregated result (as mentioned in the OP)

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

result = Foo.objects.aggregate(
    simple_json_total=models.Sum(
        Cast("simple_json__amount", output_field=models.IntegerField()),
    ),
    nested_json_total=models.Sum(
        Cast("nested_json__l1__l2__l3__amount", output_field=models.IntegerField()),
    ),
)

# Result
# {'simple_json_total': 92, 'nested_json_total': 39}
```

---

### For `Django==3.1.X` and older versions

You can use the **`KeyTextTransform(...)`** to extract the keys and aggregate the values.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models.fields.json import KeyTextTransform as KT

simple_kt_expr = KT('amount', 'simple_json')
nested_kt_expr = KT("amount", KT("l3", KT("l2", KT("l1", "nested_json"))))
result = Foo.objects.aggregate(
    simple_json_total=models.Sum(Cast(simple_kt_expr, output_field=models.IntegerField())),
    nested_json_total=models.Sum(Cast(nested_kt_expr, output_field=models.IntegerField())),

)

# Result
# {'simple_json_total': 92, 'nested_json_total': 39}
```

If you are using ***`PostgreSQL`*** and don't want to use the *"nested  usage of `KeyTextTransform`"*, you can create a custom Django DB function equivalent to the [***`jsonb_extract_path_text(...)`***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

```py
from django.db.models import Aggregate


class JSONBExtractPathText(Aggregate):
    function = 'jsonb_extract_path_text'
    template = None

    def get_template(self):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/38985104/8283848
        paths = str(self.extra['path'])[1:-1]
        return f"%(function)s(%(jsonb_field)s, {paths})"

    def as_sql(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["template"] = self.get_template()
        return super().as_sql(*args, **kwargs)
```

and it can be used as

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

simple_expr = JSONBExtractPathText(path=["amount"], jsonb_field="simple_json")
nested_expr = JSONBExtractPathText(path=["l1", "l2", "l3", "amount"], jsonb_field="nested_json")
result = Foo.objects.aggregate(
    simple_json_total=models.Sum(Cast(simple_expr, output_field=models.IntegerField())),
    nested_json_total=models.Sum(Cast(nested_expr, output_field=models.IntegerField())),

)

# Result
# {'simple_json_total': 92, 'nested_json_total': 39}
```

---

#### References

1. [Aggregate Django `JSONField`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76160437/8283848)
2. Django tickets - [#26511](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26511), [#33966](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33966)
3. Django PR - [#16016](https://github.com/django/django/pull/16016/)
4. [String join without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38985104/8283848)